In Unity, my FPS character accelerates when going diagonally
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController Controller;


    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f * 2;
    public float JumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;

    bool isGrounded;
    bool isMoving;

    private Vector3 lastPosition = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);

    void Start()
    {
        Controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }


    void Update()
    {

        //Karakter yere değiyormu.
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        Debug.Log("Birim karedeki hız: " + Controller.velocity.magnitude);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }


        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        Controller.Move(move*speed*Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        
        velocity.y += gravity*Time.deltaTime;


        Controller.Move(velocity*Time.deltaTime);

        if(lastPosition != gameObject.transform.position && isGrounded == true)
        {
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }

    }
}

I am trying to make an FPS game, the code above is the character's movement codes, but the character speeds up when going diagonally. The reason for this problem is that the speed of the character increases when trying to go in two directions while going diagonally or something else? Also, how do I measure the speed of the character, the speed it travels per unit frame.GAME ENGINE UNITY

This isn't a perfect solution, but it's pretty good.
Vector2 inVector = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
if(inVector.magnitude > 1) { inVector.Normalize(); }
Vector3 move = transform.right * inVector.x + transform.forward * inVector.y;
